# How compiler make's sure that no data member state is changed in the const member function? (either in C++ or java)

Tags: c++, constants

How can a C++ or Java compiler make sure that none of the member variables state is changed in a `const` member function (mutable is exceptional).

Will the compiler do something like putting the code in a non-writable code segment or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't make sure.  It can't, since there's no rule
in the language that says that member variable state cannot
change in a `const` member function.  The only rule is that you
cannot change the state through the `this` pointer (without
casting away `const`).

Comment: OK.  I'll raise a DR, because this is not intentional (and is contradicted in many other places in the standard).  You can modify `mutable` (otherwise, what's the point), you can cast away const, and you can clearly modify the object through other, non-const pointers to it which may exist.

Comment: @James:  Many of these activities result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @John Which?  They're all perfectly defined according to the standard.

Comment: @James: I was referring to the general idea of casting away const, not in the specific context of your original answer.  For instance, `const char* str = "hello"; char* that = const_cast<char*>(str); that[0] = '\0';` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @John There are certainly contexts where casting away const can get you into trouble:-).  If will even cause undefined behavior if you do it to the `this` pointer, and the actual object was declared `const`.  The DR will only concern the passage you pointed out, which is clearly in error.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ `const` checking is done at compile time through the logic of the compiler. It will ensure that if a function is marked `const` then no changes will be made to the member variables. I don't think it has anything to do with the storage of the executable code.

For Java, I wasn't aware that there was the same `const` paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ compiler will flag an error if you try to modify a member variable (directly or indirectly by calling a non-const function) in a const function (unless that variable is marked as mutable). You can get around this with a cast. The compiler will not (and should not) do anything more to enforce constness at run-time.

I can't speak to Java.

Answer (score 0):

In C++: `const` qualifier of the function just makes every non-mutable member of the class and `this` pointer const-qualified within this function body. That's all.

**ADD:**

It means that if const-function explicitly or implicitly accesses `this` pointer as non-const pointer it will produce compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

**In C++**: The compiler detects obvious errors, that is callings of a non-const function on a member variable (or the this object). It includes calling operator=, etc. It will usually output "cannot convert from const ...T... to ...T...".

If you want to bypass that, you can use `const_cast`.

It should be noted though that the constness of a function does NOT mean that the state of the object won't change after a call to. For example, with that code :

```
class A
{
public:
  // stuff...
  //
  int* getPointer() const {return mpA;}
private:
  int* mpA;
}
```

you can have access to the value pointed to by mpA from the outside and modify it... The object mpA itself won't be modified (so the constness of getPointer is respected), but the constness of the value that mpA points to is not guaranteed. It would indeed be too much work to guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the `const` qualifier is a qualifier on the type. Actually, a const-qualified named is (after the standard) an *elaborated type*.

When performing function overload resolution, the compilers will thus apply the regular mechanism that prevents you from calling `void foo(int)` with a `std::string` as argument for example.

They may have, though, better diagnostics for this specific error, to help the developer.

In C++, this is especially illustrated by the fact that `const_cast` is available to remove the *const-ness* of an object... There is only *one* subtlety:

Objects that are instantiated at file scope (globals, statics, ...) and declared `const` may be placed in read-only memory at the discretion of the compiler, in which case attempting a `const_cast` is *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

And one more to addition the above points to make it simple.
In const functions , compiler makes it to constant pointer.
so const int a =10;, a= 20 obviously throws errors.